# Kafka data loss (when LAG is over 20,000)

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka

when putting data into Producer - Kafka - Logiste - Elastic Search.
At this time, if the Kafka accumulates more than 20,000 data (if the consumer can not take it), all of a sudden it becomes read.
In other words, if the LAG exceeds 20000, it equals CURRENT-OFFSETdl LOG-END-OFFSET.

I do not know why.
I did not experience it before.
You know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the message retention configuration of your Kafka cluster.
Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311100/kafka-optimal-retention-and-deletion-policy) answer or [this](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) documentation. Search for 'log.retention' in the Kafka documentation.